# Is there are way to prevent apitrace from tracing the release version of an OpenGL program?

Tags: opengl, trace

Is there a way to prevent [apitrace](http://apitrace.github.io/) from dumping OpenGL calls?

Currently the `apitrace` can dump everything, is there a way to stop it for release version?

Answer (score 3):

No.

There is no reasonable way to do that. OpenGL is usually implemented just as a dynamic library, and one can always exchange that or hook on every function call. That is also not limited to GL.